# How an image is distorted if we orbit camera along one axis

Tags: image

Say i've an image of some geometrical objects on a plane: the image is taken from an orthogonal POV.

[image: orthogonal]

I would like to understand how this image gets distorted if the camera orbits along one axis (say x-axis):
[image: distorted image]

(The images above are taken using blender in order to be able to explain my problem, obviously the images i want to rotate are simple png)

I tried to work with homography, however it doesn't fit my problem as i don't have any destination points. How can i approach this problem from a geometrical stands point, any advise?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I post it hoping it may help someone else; I warn I'm an amateur programmer, this code solved my problem but it may not work on yours.

The key theorical contribution is from scratchapixel.com
https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/computing-pixel-coordinates-of-3d-point/mathematics-computing-2d-coordinates-of-3d-points

Here the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
from skimage import transform
import numpy as np
import math

def omography(img,src,dst):
    tform3 = transform.ProjectiveTransform()
    tform3.estimate(dst, src)
    warped = transform.warp(img, tform3, output_shape=(int(np.amax(dst[:,1])+50),int(np.amax(dst[:,0])+50)))
    warped = warped[int(np.amin(dst[:,1])-50):,int(np.amin(dst[:,0])-50):]
    return warped

def getProjectedVertex(alfa):
    angle = math.radians(alfa)
    dist = 20
    MatriceWorldToCamera = np.array([[1,0,0,0],
                                   [0,math.sin(angle),math.cos(angle),0],
                                   [0,-math.cos(angle),math.sin(angle),-dist],
                                   [0,0,0,1]])
    projectedVertex = []
    #python adaptation of https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/computing-pixel-coordinates-of-3d-point/mathematics-computing-2d-coordinates-of-3d-points
    for p in originalVertex:
        pCamera = MatriceWorldToCamera.dot(p)

        pScreenX = pCamera[0]/-pCamera[2]
        pScreenY = pCamera[1]/-pCamera[2]
        pScreen = [pScreenX,pScreenY]

        pNDCX = (pScreen[0] + canvasW/2)/canvasW
        pNDCY = (pScreen[1] + canvasH/2)/canvasH
        pNDC = [pNDCX,pNDCY]

        pRasterX = pNDC[0]*outputW
        pRasterY = (1-pNDC[1])*outputH
        pRaster = [pRasterX,pRasterY]

        projectedVertex.append(pRaster)
    projectedVertex = np.array(projectedVertex)
    return projectedVertex

def on_trackbar(alfa):
    vDst = getProjectedVertex(alfa)
    output = omography(IMAGE,vSrc,vDst)
    cv.imshow('window', output)

#INPUT
imagePath = r'C:\Users\img.png'
resX,resY = (1920,1080)
ratio = resY/resX
canvasW = 1
canvasH = canvasW*ratio
outputW = 4000
outputH = outputW*ratio

# get image you want to distort
IMAGE = cv.imread(imagePath)
IMAGE = cv.cvtColor(IMAGE,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgY,imgX = np.shape(IMAGE)
#get the vertices of the image (they're gonna be feed in the omography function)
vSrc = np.array([[0,imgY],[imgX,imgY],[imgX,0],[0,0]])
#assuming square
originalVertex = np.array([[-1,-1],[1,-1],[1,1],[-1,1]]) #square centered in 0,0
originalVertex = np.column_stack((originalVertex, [0,0,0,0])) #add z-coordinates (0 as are on the same planes)
originalVertex = np.column_stack((originalVertex, [1,1,1,1])) #add fourth value equal to 1 to allow matrix product later on
#create output window
cv.namedWindow('window')
trackbar_name = 'Angle'
cv.createTrackbar(trackbar_name, 'window' , 1,90, on_trackbar)
# Wait until user press some key
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here the input image and the outputs:
[image]